Convert HTML table to flexbox - how to mimic td with rowspan="2"
I have a HTML table that I am trying to replace with divs using flexbox.
I have most of it working but I cannot figure out to replicate the look of a td with rowspan="2".
This is my HTML table and the related CSS:


#divMain table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#divMain table tr {
  height: 100px;
}

#divMain table td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}
<div id="divMain">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">blah</td>
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blah</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>



This is my set of divs using flexbox and the related CSS:


.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.cell {
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: top;
}
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
  </div>
</div>



In this picture the red chunk is a td with rowspan="2". How do I achieve the same when using divs with flexbox?


Why would you want to use flexbox here? The obvious choice for replacing an actual table would be grid.

If you want something that looks like a table then you may want to take a look at using CSS grid instead of flexbox. Flexbox is not intended to be used like this.

Ah. I was instructed to replace it with flexbox. I'll look at CSS grid instead. Thanks for the input.

As suggested in the comments, you can achieve this easily with CSS Grid instead of Flexbox:


    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .table {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .cell {
        height: 100px;
        vertical-align: top;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: yellow;
    }

    .cell.rowspan {
        height: 200px;
        grid-row: span 2;
    }
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell rowspan">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
    <div class="cell">blah</div>
</div>



We have used grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) to define three equal-width columns, and grid-row: span 2 to make the rowspan span two rows.

Brilliant, thank very much m-sarabi
